# Database queries in an Apache Flink Stream

Tags: mongodb, stream, hbase, apache-flink

I am learning Apache Flink and very impressed by that. The data treatment technique used there is exciting and breaks my brain :)

But where I am stacked now is mixing the streams and batches. What I mean. I have a stream handler which receives some data. For example, this data is commands. For handling such a command I need to make a query to a database (HBase or Mongo) and of course the query depends on the command. The database is huge (several terabytes). Both HBase and Mongo allow parallel operations through MapReduce and it would be great to use that. After the series of requests some parallel calculations are implied with the final sending the results to a sink.

So, how can it be solved in the best? Sould I make standart database queries in a flatMap or use DataSet/Stream?

Comment: It seems that your streaming job will access external DB while flatMapping data. One option is to use AsyncIO in Flink Streaming. Please refer to AsyncIOExample for actual usage. AsyncIO will process multiple input records in parallel way, accessing external DB at the same time. Another way is to increase the parallelism of the task, just like Map/Reduce tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will certainly use that.